# embedding .exe applications on a QT form

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to know if its possible to embed other .exe applications on a QT form.
Say i have an app called foo.exe. Now I want to lauch foo.exe through my application. I know I could do that using `QProcess::startDetached()` however I would like that program to run within my form.Is that possible ?

Comment: I searched several times on "embed" in order to create a multi-process program (like google chrome), but there was no result in window, the one I got was in X11 (in QT `#include <QX11EmbedContainer>`).

Comment: I believe the embedded executable would still have to be extracted to run in windows.

Comment: Wait a minute.. Do you just want to execute some an external console based app and have its output appear inside your form? I have done that with QProcess and the signals and slots it supports for capturing output. I could give you an example of this.

Comment: No i am attempting to run a GUI application

Answer (score 1):

Believe what you want is a kind of "EMBED", there seems to be something done, but I can direct you to a few ways:

### Cygwin

In [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) we have o "X-Embed"

For Windows exists [Cygwin/X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin/X) (apparently to run "multi-threaded" in "google chrome" uses cygwin).

QT X11 Systems: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvfb.html

Nice example: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/03/experimental-process-per-tab-browser-created-with-qt-xembed/ (outdated)

### ActiveX

You can create Activex Controls, see example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/activeqt-server.html

---

In two suggestions that you spent the programs you want to add to your main program should be created by you, in other words, programs that are not compiled with "Cygwin" or is not an "ActiveX" (QT you can add controls ActiveX, such as Internet Explorer or MSExcel).

Believe both examples programs work as "servers" and its main program as a "client", in other words, other processes need not necessarily one graphical interface, I believe the main software is who works the GUI part.

For this reason the programs should be "embedded" created with the purpose of "embedding"

---

### Alternative solution (DotNet and user32.dll)

See article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project